# Is there a convolution function in Tensorflow to apply a Sobel filter?

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolution, sobel

Is there any `convolution` method in Tensorflow to apply a Sobel filter to an image `img` (tensor of type `float32` and rank 2)?

```
sobel_x = tf.constant([[-1, 0, 1], [-2, 0, 2], [-1, 0, 1]], 'float32')
result = tf.convolution(img, sobel_x) # <== TO DO THIS
```

I've already seen `tf.nn.conv2d` but I can't see how to use it for this operation. Is there some way to use `tf.nn.conv2d` to solve my problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing a subtlety here, but it appears that you could apply a Sobel filter to an image using [`tf.expand_dims()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#expand_dims) and [`tf.nn.conv2d()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/nn.html#conv2d), as follows:

```
sobel_x = tf.constant([[-1, 0, 1], [-2, 0, 2], [-1, 0, 1]], tf.float32)
sobel_x_filter = tf.reshape(sobel_x, [3, 3, 1, 1])
sobel_y_filter = tf.transpose(sobel_x_filter, [1, 0, 2, 3])

# Shape = height x width.
image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None])

# Shape = 1 x height x width x 1.
image_resized = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(image, 0), 3)

filtered_x = tf.nn.conv2d(image_resized, sobel_x_filter,
                          strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
filtered_y = tf.nn.conv2d(image_resized, sobel_y_filter,
                          strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```

Comment: When finished I found it could be applied tf.squeeze(filtered_x). Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more how does it work?
How can I actually convolve a real image and show it?

Comment: There is a typo in the second "sobel_x_filter" (soble_x_filter).

Comment: @OliasailO Thanks for pointing that out! I've updated the code.

Comment: your sobel_x filter is not correct.
`tf.constant([[1, 0, -1], [2, 0, -2], [1, 0, -1]], tf.float32)`  the most left must be swapped with the most right.

Answer (score 3):

Tensorflow 1.8 has added tf.image.sobel_edges() so that is the easiest and probably most robust way todo this now.